# Using const in header-file

Tags: c++, header, constants

in file.h:

```
 extern const int ONE;
```

in file.cpp

```
#include "file.h"
const int ONE = 1;
```

and in main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "file.h"
int main()
{
    std::cout << ONE << std::endl;
}
```

The question: Why must i use `#include "file.h"` in file.cpp? There is a definition of `ONE`.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, variables declared `const` have internal linkage, as if they were also declared `static`. If you include the header, then the `extern` declaration will give it external linkage and all will be fine. Otherwise, the definition isn't available from other translation units.

You could avoid including the header by adding `extern` to the definition; but it's better to include the header anyway so the compiler can check that the two declarations are compatible.

Better still might be to define it with internal linkage in the header,

```
const int ONE = 1;
```

with no definition in the source file; then its value is available as a constant expression.

Comment: Can you tell more about what you mean when you say "anything that requires its address"?

Comment: @alexolut: For example, taking its address with `&`, or creating a reference to it. Doing these requires it to exist at a well-defined memory location, which requires a definition. Just using its value doesn't, as long as the value is available as a constant expression.

Comment: But i can take an address of 'const int i=42' declared in .h-file when I include it in .cpp-file. I tried it on compileonline.com (but there seems to be impossible to give a link to the code).

Comment: @alexolut: If you just declare it `const`, then it's a definition with internal linkage - you can take the address, and you'll get different addresses in each translation unit. If you add `extern` (so it's just a declaration), then you can't take the address unless there's also a definition somewhere - but you can still use the value.

Comment: And the final question: which form of `const` better to use (in .h-file) if I want just a value (and gives me error when i'll try to take an address)? `extern const int i=42`? `const int i=42`? Which one?

Comment: @alexolut: If, as you say, you particularly want to prevent taking the address, the first. As I said, the second is a definition, so you can take the address of that. But the second is nearly always better, since it can be passed to functions like `std::min` which take their arguments by reference.

Comment: I got an error `multiple definition of 'i'` when I wrote first form and include .h-file to both .cpp

Comment: @alexolut: Yes, you're right, the first form is also a definition since it contains both `extern` and an initialiser. I was getting mixed up with static member variables. If you want to know all the details of how declarations and definitions work, you might find a book more helpful than my unreliable memory.

Answer (score 3):

> There is a definition of ONE.

A *definition*, yes. But the important thing about including the header file in `file.cpp` is that it provides a different *declaration* of `ONE` – namely, one that is marked `extern`. This prevents the subsequently defined `ONE` constant from having internal linkage and thus not being exported.

In order to make the *definition* of `ONE`, which is in a separate compilation unit, visible to `main.cpp`, `ONE`’s linkage must not be internal.